# Easily implement interface on 3rd party DLL

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I'm creating an interface on a 3rd party DLL so that I can use it over WCF.  The implementation looks like this:

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterfaceFor3rdPartyClass
{
  public ThirdPartyClass TPC = new ThirdPartyClass();

  int MethodA()
  {
    return TPC.MethodA();
  }

  int MethodB(int someParameter)
  {
    return TPC.MethodB(someParameter);
  }
}
```

However, there are about 50 methods and I really don't feel like implementing every one.  Is there an easier way than hand typing the entire thing?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I've already had VS "auto implement" all the method names which generates the method names and `throw new NotImplementedException();`.

**Edit**
Just had a thought: can the 3rd party class somehow implement the interface?

Comment: This is the kind of stuff I think ReSharper can do https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html

Comment: ... and [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422998/243245) says ReSharper calls this ['delegating members'](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html). (I'd have called it 'Facade'.)

Comment: That looks promising.

Comment: About your Edit - Doesn't `ThirdPartyClass` already implement the interface? from sample code above, it "looks" like it does.. but then, it might not..

Comment: this may or may not help as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042605/how-can-subclasses-share-behavior-when-one-already-derives-from-a-different-base

Comment: @VikasGupta The interface was derived from the class, but since I derived it, it doesn't *explicitly* implement the interface.  Is there someway to do that?

Comment: Does your interface has all public methods with same declaration as in the third party class?

Comment: @danish Yes, it matches exactly

Comment: Update method stub snippet here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring. You can try to ensure that whenever the interface is implemented, method body will look like TPC.<CallToCurrentMethod>. I cannot figure out what the syntax is to do this in snippets.